# Cheat Sheet for CodeRush Xpress for VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coderush-xpress

Is there a cheat sheet / keymap available for CodeRush Xpress for VS 2010?

The best I have found [is this](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/CodeRushShortcutsAndTemplates.pdf).

but this is for the full version of CodeRush, and is for the 2008 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no cheat sheet available for CodeRush **Xpress** on VS2010, and no usable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The cheat sheet you found has been replaced with the [CodeRush Keyboard Mapping Window](http://help.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument11759). Most likely, the cheat sheet will not be updated any longer. However, the listed shortcuts work for both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: The "CodeRush Keyboard Mapping Window" is a good alternative except CTRL+ALT+/ doesn't do anything for me, and I don't have a "Keyboard Mapping" options page to configure it. The IDE section of the options tree only has Shortcuts and User Info. I'm using VS 2010 ultimate and CodeRush express 11.2.12

Comment: The CodeRush Keyboard Mapping is available since release 12.1 and only in the full CodeRush version.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. However, my question and the tags I gave it both refer to CodeRush **Xpress**, so I wasted a lot of time looking for a window that didn't exist. Also, v. 11.2.12 is the latest on the devexpress website - mention of version 12.1 is confusing.

Comment: You are correct, I should have mentioned this in the initial response. I apologize for that. And yes, 11.2.12 is the latest available version of the free CodeRush.